# React native: Avoid screen going light before blur effect

Tags: react-native, blur

I have a background image, and I want to blur it out more and more. 
So far the blurring works fine:

```
export default class Example extends Component {

  state = { blurState: 1 };

  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.getRandomBlurIntervals();
  }

  getRandomBlurIntervals = () => {
    var blurState = this.state.blurState;
    setInterval(() => {
      blurState = blurState + Math.random();
      this.setState({blurState});
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={require('../images/awesomeImage.jpg')}
        blurRadius = {this.state.blurState}
        style={styles.backgroundImage}>
          <Text >Some awesome text</Text>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null
  }
});
```

My problem is, that when changing from blurry state to the next one, the screen goes light for a moment, like it's reloading the page. 
I do not need a super smooth transition from one blur state to the other, but I want to get rid of these white flashed screens. 
Is there any setting that helps avoiding them?

(I don't know if `react-native-blur` would solve this better, but I am currently using expo, so I cannot use that one.)